# reading from some code and saving the result as a tuple

Tags: c++

I'm using a program for work in which i have to read some warehouse data in the form of: string integer double for a whole bunch of items

but they are the same items every time (in this case) I don't know where the data is stored (or how it is stored) so I end up writing the data every single time.

To complicate things there are more tuples for which I have to use many nested for loops, which adds to runtime.

Is there any way for me to read the data once and save in a textfile so I can have it hardcoded for the future?

e.g. if i read: "COKE" 5 1.99

how can i make a file that says:

tuple = {"COKE", 5, 1.99};

Comment: Try be more specific and share some code. Also from where do you have to read tuples?

Comment: Search the web for "c++ comma separated values file".  See also "c++ tab separated values".  Also search for XML, and INI formats.

Comment: So the question basically is how to write to a textfile in c++?

Comment: there is just a function that reads the data - not sure how the underlying interface works or the data structure that is used

tuple<string,int,double> data

for(i =0; i < numItems; i++) {
data = getItem(i); //Don't know how this function works
}

Comment: yes i guess so but the thing is I know how to write a text file but I don't want to have to read the data when the program starts up

Comment: is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct My_Tuple
{
  std::string text;
  int         number;
  double      floating_point;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const My_Tuple& m);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const My_Tuple& m)
{
  out << "\"" << text << "\",";
  out << number << ",";
  out << floating_point << "\n";
  return out;
}

int main(void)
{
  My_Tuple m = {"Hello", 16, 3.14159};
  cout << m;
  return 0;
}
```

Overloading the stream insertion operator allows you to output the object to an `std::ofstream` without changing the structure.

**Edit 1:**
For those people who can't fathom how to adapt to a file:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::ofstream file("My_Tuples.txt");
  My_Tuple m = {"Big Mac", -6, 2.72};
  file << m;
  file.close(); // Not needed, but it is explicit.
  return 0;
}
```